# Is it possible to use continue keyword outside a loop in C++?

Tags: c++, goto, continue

According to ISO C++:

> The continue statement shall occur only in an iteration-statement and
> causes control to pass to the loop-continuation portion of the smallest
> enclosing iteration-statement, that is, to the end of the loop. More
> precisely, in each of the statements
>
> ```
> while (foo) {           do {                    for(;;){
>   {                     {                       {
>       // ...              //....                 //...
>   }                     }                       }
>   contin:;             contin:;                contin:;
>   }                    } while (foo);           }
> ```
>
> a **continue** not contained in an enclosed iteration statement is
> equivalent to goto contin

Based on the last part of the quote, I thought that the following would be allowed:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    continue;
    cout << "Will be jumped" << endl;
contin:
}
```

I thought this will work as a goto statement, jumping to `contin`. What did I miss?

Comment: `continue` **only** works in loops

Comment: It seems you misunderstand the examples. What is shown in the examples (as well as the examples in [this `continue` online reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue)) is *equivalence* not actual behavior. Using `continue` ***in a loop*** is *equivalent* to using `goto some_label;` where `some_label` is placed at the end of the loop.

Comment: When the standard uses italics for identifiers like *contin*, those are exposition-only identifiers and cannot be referred to from C++ code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is slight phrasing issue. What the quote means is that in

```
for (;;) {
  {
    // ...
  }
contin: ;
}
```

The `...` can be anything, including another iteration statement.

```
for (;;) {
  {
    while(foo()) {
        // ...
        continue;
    }
  }
contin: ;
}
```

The `continue;` that *is not* nested inside another looping construct, is going to be equivalent to `goto contin;`. But if it is contained, it will of course continue the internal loop, not the outer one.

Bear in mind that `contin: ;` is used for exposition purposes. It doesn't mean there's a literal C++-level label you can do things with.